# Playbak device not recognized when using HDMI

Tags: audio, hdmi, playback

I recently purchased a new laptop that came with windows 8.1 . When I first got the computer I tested that when I plug in my HDMI cable into the computer and connect it with the TV, the TV is recognized as an audio playback device, which I could set to default (I checked this because for the last laptop I bought this did not work, just like now, so they exchanged it with this one). When I tested this it worked, the tv was recognized as a playback device and when sound was output it would come out of the tv.
Now when I plug in the HDMI cable the tv is not recognized as a playback device.
Since when I tested it, the only changes to the computer that I can think of is software that I installed.

I installed:

Classic Shell

Eset Nod32

Windows Office 13

VLC

Matlab

I thought maybe it was the Nod32 so i disabled and it and tried, but this did not help.
Any suggestions?

EDIT: I did a system restore to before I installed any of the software and it still did not work